# How to resolve constructor injection to pass specific class as a parameter using unity dependency

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, unity-container

I have an interface for Data Access Layer (IDal)

```
public interface IDal<T>{
 void Write(T object);
 T Read();
}
```

And I have two classes that has implemented this interface, which access data from two different source.

```
public class Source1<T>:IDal<T>{
 public void Write(T object){ }
 public T Read(T object){ }
}

public class Source2<T>:IDal<T>{
 public void Write(T object){ }
 public T Read(T object){ }
}
```

And I have a common service interface

```
public interface IService<T>{
    T Get(int id);
    T Save(T obj);
    T Update(T obj);
    T Delete(int id);
}
```

and I have a service class that has imeplemented service interface

```
public class Service<T> : IService<T>{
 IDal<T> _dal;

 public Service(IDal<T> dal){
    _dal = dal;
 }

 public T Get(int id) { }

 public T Save(T obj) { }

 public T Update(T obj) { }

 public T Delete(int id) { }
}
```

And I have two different controller

```
public class Bank1Controller(){
 IService<Bank1Properties> _service;

 public Bank1Controller(IService<Bank1Properties> service){
    _service = service
 }
}

public class Bank2Controller(){
 IService<Bank2Properties> _service;

 public Bank2Controller(IService<Bank2Properties> service){
    _service = service
 }
}
```

here i want to inject Source1 DAL to Bank1 and Source2 to Bank2 from Unity Dependency
Since both source1 and source2 are inherited from IDal.

```
container.RegisterType<IService<Bank1Properties>, Service<Bank1Properties>>();
container.RegisterType<IDal<Bank1Properties>, Source1<Bank1Properties>>();
container.RegisterType<IDal<Bank2Properties>, Source2<Bank2Properties>>();
```

Here my both controller try to acces source2, but i want to inject Bank1 = source1 and Bank2 = source2. 
How do i conditionaly resolve it.

If i register  the type this way, it works perfectly, 
but I don't know this is good way or not. Is there any better way.

```
container.RegisterType<Bank1Controller>(new InjectionConstructor(
 new Service<Bank1Properties>(new Source1<Bank1Properties>())
));

container.RegisterType<Bank2Controller>(new InjectionConstructor(
 new Service<Bank2Properties>(new Source1<Bank2Properties>())
));
```

Comment: Well I was in the middle of writing an answer before it got marked as a duplicate...

Comment: I don't actually agree it's a duplicate.  Anyhow I think what you've done is perfectly valid, but maybe a little useless. You need to have a reason for using injection, rather than injecting because that's what everyone says good code does.  Injection is suppose to be useful.... I would think about what controllers you have and what services they're likely to require.  What the relationships between your services and controllers are.... is it 1 to 1?  Could a service be used by more than one controller etc etc

Comment: I'd suggest if the services <-> controller relationship is 1 : 1 why not simply inject as public Bank1Controller(Source1<Bank1Properties> service) ?
Then container.RegisterType<Source1<Bank1Properties>, Source1<Bank1Properties>>();

I'm more familiar with Autofac injection at the moment so I'm not sure if that's the best way to register a type to itself in autofac it would be builder.RegisterType<Source1<Bank1Properties>>().AsSelf();